# How to make a phone think it has a battery on it and run it from a charger

Tags: batteries, cellphone, smartphones

Im trying to run  a samsung galaxy s7 edge without a battery on it but it just turn on shows a logo and then turns off again i think it knows that there is not a battery inside so if anyone knows what to connect to make it think it has one or what i can do

Comment: it is possible that the charger does not provide enough current to allow a voice call

Comment: The current pump needs a large  cap or battery to stabilize the regulator voltage.

Comment: MAYBE a larger capacity supply or a large capacitor across the supply BUT the phone may be detecting battery presence specifically. || Adding a well used battery with low capacity may satisfy it. || You MAY be able to provide a voltage in the 3.2 - 4.0 V range to the battery terminals. This needs to be able to absorb charge. || OR a voltage presented to the battery terminals of 4.2 to 4.25 v may work. The battery MAY be a "smart battery" with internal electronics, in which case a real battery may be the only easy solution.

Comment: Simple Li-Ion battery packs connect to the phone with three wires. BATT+, BATT- and NTC. The NTC is a negative temperature coefficient resistor. Usually 10K ohms at 25°C. Try a 10K resistor connected between the NTC and BATT- terminals on the phone and apply 3.7 volts DC on the BATT terminals.

Comment: I have seen this question asked in several sites and no one has ever reported success, so it may be impossible.